# Run script before every Time Machine backup?

Tags: time-machine, bash, script

I would like to be able to run a *bash* script just before Time Machine runs, every time
This script generates some content to be written on a file which needs to be backed up by TM.

I have looked around, but surprisingly no one seemed to have asked this before. Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not possible as far as I know. There aren't any real “hooks” into Time Machine.

However, you can do something *nearly* as good: you can disable the automatic backups that Time Machine does and run it manually instead:

```
#!/bin/sh

run_your_command_here

run_another_command_here

and_so_on

tmutil startbackup --block --auto

exit 0
```

Note this bit from [man tmutil](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man8/tmutil.8.html)

> The --auto option provides a supported mechanism with which to
>   trigger "automatic-like" backups, similar to automatic backups
>   that are scheduled by the system. While this is not identical
>   to true system-scheduled backups, it provides custom schedulers
>   the ability to achieve some (but not all) behavior normally
>   exhibited when operating in automatic mode.

It is not clear to me what the difference is, but it's worth noting that one exists.

Comment: And how do you run the script every hour, then? Using launchd?

Comment: Exactly. I recommend http://www.soma-zone.com/LaunchControl/ for making changes to launchd.